# How to make css smaller?

Tags: css

I have a CSS file which styles the entire page, and it's getting Gzipped and it's minified, but it's still 200kb. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: 200KB? What on earth is in there? I very much suspect that you have other issues to address if the file is really this large.

Comment: same question. What is in there? You should get rid of repetitive statements, define some general classes for some behaviors...

Comment: and also, you could take a look @ css validator => http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: cleancss.com must help you :)

Comment: It's it's 200KB *after being gzipped*, that means it must be *freaking massive* before being gzipped. Are you sure you have your numbers right here?

Comment: I have a webapp for the iPad and it's basically all HTML and JS, but to make it look good I use css (of course). Now I have no idea if this is bad practice but I have small images and use data urls to reduce callbacks to the server, but it adds space to the css. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Yea, as I suspect, it is the data urls...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I took at look at your profile and found www.charliecarver.me, took a look at that and found a css file. If this is your website and the css file you are talking about, you repeat a lot of statements. For example, line 1 to 13 of your css file looks like this:

```
body {
/** css code... **/
}
```

Line 15 to 17 looks like this:

```
body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,code,form,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td {
/** css code... **/
}
```

Line 432 to 434:

```
html>body #content {
/** css code... **/
}
```

Line 826 to 828:

```
body,td,th,.metadata a:link,.metadata a:visited,.navigation a:link,.navigation {
/** css code... **/
}
```

All that could be done with one block of code referencing the body. So, Reduce the amount of repeats you have. Just to give you an idea of what's repeating:

The elements:

- "div" appears 35 times
- "dt" appears 50 times
- "dd" appears 30 times
- "ol" appears 49 times
- "li" appears 6 times
- "yui" appears 315 times

Also, using only what you need will greatly reduce the size.

Comment: Not that site haha, my other one. But thank you for taking the time to look at my site and help me out. Very good.

Comment: Sure thing. If you do it on one site you're probably bound to do it on another. So just keep in mind the above and the size of your css files should shrink accordingly.

Comment: Ok, thanks. On my other site the problem is data urls which was making the file huge. Guess I should take them out.

Comment: If you don't care much for readability you could leave them in there. I'm not 100% sure on this, but I believe direct linking to image files takes two http requests, while data:uri's only take one. Still, if you want to reduce the size of your css files, using data:uri's are not the way to go. ;)

Comment: Right, so I have to decide between a bigggggg css file with data urls but having my site only make 4 requests, as opposed to like 14 requests and having a small css file. What do you think is better?

Comment: @Charlie Removing the data-urls for larger well-cachable items. Browsers have handled this fine for years.

Comment: Yes. Even if you have two images and combine it into one. That's 2 requests (I believe) instead of 4, disregarding the cache.